# Use a CSV file to parameterize commands executed on remote machines

Tags: powershell, csv

I am working on this all night and now i think i need help :-)
A am new to Powershell and i already did a lot of research but i cant find the right answer, i hope someone here can help me.

What i am trying to do is deploy a IIS Application to a couple of servers.
I managed to add the application to a website, in my case i used the "Default Web Site" with the following code:

```
Get-Content c:\scripts\servers.txt | Foreach {  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ {Import-Module WebAdministration ; New-WebApplication -Site "Default Web Site" -Name TestRico2 -PhysicalPath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\} }
```

This is the content of the servers.txt:

WEB01
WEB02
WEB03

And that is actually working fine. But the thing i would like to achieve is that the other items are also dynamically:

```
-Site "Default Web Site"  
-Name TestRico2  
-PhysicalPath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\
```

So, i want to have a CSV file like:

```
server,site,name,path  
WEB01,Default Web Site,Application-name,c:\inetpub\wwwroot\  
WEB02,Default Web Site,Application-name2,c:\inetpub\wwwroot2\
```

I have no clue anymore, is there anyone out there who could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Import-Csv` reads CSV files and represents each input row as a custom object whose properties are named for the CSV column headers, and whose values are the respective rows' column values.

Therefore, use `Import-Csv` instead of `Get-Content` and access the values of interest as properties of the input object at hand, `$_`:

```
Import-Csv c:\scripts\servers.csv | ForEach-Object { 
  Invoke-Command ComputerName $_.server  { 
    param($site, $name, $path)
    Import-Module WebAdministration; 
    New-WebApplication -Site $site -Name $name -PhysicalPath $path
  } -Args $_.site, $_.name, $_.path
}
```

Note how properties `$_.site`, `$_.name`, `$_.path` are passed as *arguments* to the script block passed to `Invoke-Command`, because the script block is executed on the *target machine*, where the *local* variables aren't available.

In PSv3+ or higher, the alternative to passing arguments is to use the `$using:` scope to refer to local variables directly inside the script block - see
[Get-Help about_Remote_Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Remote_Variables).